# How to remove the state of a GlobalKTable store?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to remove the state of my `GlobalKTable<Integer, Long>` store.

I tried to remove the state by:

- deleting the entire Kafka topic by calling `kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:8080 --delete --topic my-topic`
- running `KafkaStreams.cleanUp()` on application startup
- producing a 'Test:null' message to my stream, as null values should be treated as a DELETE statement in the store, as described [here](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/developer-guide#streams_dsl_source). However, my streams application fails as the null value can not be deserialized to LONG.

See the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:546)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:920)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:821)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
```

How to remove the state of my GlobalKTable?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to solve this. To remove the entire state of the GlobalKTable, the RocksDB cache files needs to be purged as well.

The RocksDB files are stored at location `StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG`. I've deleted the files and now my state is entirely cleaned.

There might be a better solution to do this, though?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax that makes sense. Looking forward to the release. Any comment on the exception part? How am I supposed to delete entries from my state when the Kafka Streams will throw exceptions for the null values?

Comment: Not sure about the exception. I double it's related to `GlobalKTable` because those are maintained via `GlobalStreamThread` but the exception originates from `StreamThread`. Also `LongDeserializer` can handle `null` messages. What `Serializer` do you use to write the `Test:null` message? Maybe it encodes its in an incompatible format? For this, you would either need to change the `Serializer` or the `Serdes`

Answer (score 0):

`KafkaStreams.cleanUp()` should actually delete those RocksDB files. It's a bug that is fixed in upcoming 1.1 release: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6259.